# How do I get the id of a button that was clicked? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering how I would go about getting the id (becuase it is unknown) of a button that is clicked. So when the button is clicked, I know what the id of that specific button is. There are lots of buttons on the page and I would like to know which button is pressed (they all have unique id's). Currently the buttons look like this:

```
  <button key={uuidv4()} id={this.props.keyword} value={this.props.keyword} onClick={this.props.onClick} className="removeButton">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Use `element.id`

Answer (score 14):

You can use `event.target.id` to get the ID of button clicked

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    const id = event.target.id;
    console.log(id);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button id="unique-id" onClick={this.handleClick}>Button</button>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Would this look any different if the click handler and button element are in separate components?

Comment: Asking because I am getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined` error

Comment: @dorkycam No, it won't impact if they are two components, the error is showing up because you are missing the `event` parameter somewhere along the path to the function

Comment: gotcha, i'll try it out again

Comment: How can you get the text of the button?

Comment: @Dseaster `event.target.innerText` would get you that

Comment: why is it that when you console.log(event) in the handler, you don't see the id property? or the value property?

Answer (score 13):

Well if the elements are nested `event.target` won't always work since it refers to the target that triggers the event in the first place. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) for the usage of `event.currentTarget`, which always refer to the element that the handler is bound to.

Another way to grab hold of the element and its attributes is to use [React refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). This is more general when trying to get the DOM element in React.

Answer (score 9):

I know this has already been answered but i was working with react and faced similar issue, lost 2 hours trying to figure out why event.target.id was sometimes null or an empty string

this solved it for me:

```
class Button extends React.Component {

    getButtonId = (e) => {
      console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
    }

    render() {
       return (
          <button id="yourID" onClick={this.getButtonId}>Button</button>
       );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use either event.target.[selector goes here] or event.currentTarget.[selector goes here] to solve your issue. See example code below.

```
class Button extends React.Component {

  handleId = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button id="yourID" onClick={this.handleId}>Button</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The very convenient way (not only for buttons but for list of elements) to do this is using custom attribute `data-someName` of DOM element and then reach it via `event.currentTarget.dataset.someName`

```js
const openCard = (event) => {
  console.log('event.currentTarget.dataset.id', event.currentTarget.dataset.id); // >> id
  //do more actions with id
};

<Card onClick={openCard} data-id={item.id}>
  <CardContent />
</Card>;
```

`

Answer (score 2):

There is several way to do this

1. With manipulating `onClick` function

```js
 <button key={uuidv4()} id={this.props.keyword} value={this.props.keyword} onClick={(e)=>this.props.onClick(e,this.props.keyword)} className="removeButton">Remove</button>
    
onClick = (e,id) =>{
    console.log(id);
}
```

2. Without manipulating `onClick` function

```js
<button key={uuidv4()} id={this.props.keyword} value={this.props.keyword} onClick={this.props.onClick} className="removeButton">Remove</button>

onClick = (e) =>{
  const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
  console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: When I tried this out I got a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined` error

Comment: Maybe it's because the button and onClick handler are in different components? (things are being passed as props)

Comment: If onClick is working then you should get `e`, can you replace it with this `onClick={(e)=>this.props.onClick(e)}` and let me know?

Comment: Strange because In above comment I was suggested you to pass `e` manually In this case `function` should have got `e`, can you describe more what exactly happening behind the scene?

Comment: So I have an `App` component that's a parent to a `WordTable` component that's a parent to a `Row` component that renders each button (along with other things in the row) `WordTable` takes in info from a JSON file and generates a row for every object in that file (along with this button). This button is supposed to be able to remove the row from the table and item from the JSON file

Comment: "id" happens to be "undefined" in first approach. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
function getId(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<button key={uuidv4()} id={this.props.keyword} value={this.props.keyword} onClick="getId(this.id)" className="removeButton">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

if the function to handle the event is in the same component it is best to use the `event.target.id`, this will have its limitations when you try accessing a DOM element nested as a child component as `event.target.id`. Use `event.currentTarget.id` is nested,

This happens because `event.currentTarget`
can identify the element that caused the event deep down from the child as it burbles out, while `event.target.id` will set the target as the child component and will not be able to identify the child component that has that element since it target does not change and hence faulty.

You can watch this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpatM1W5wRQ) to understand better.
also read from their [differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: to ellaborate `event.target.getAttribute('attribute_name')` will cover a wider range of scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick handler should receive the click event, which should include the id: `event.target.id`.

```
<button
  key={uuidv4()}
  id={this.props.keyword}
  value={this.props.keyword}
  onClick={(event) => /* you want to use event.target.id */}
  className="removeButton">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
functionName = (event) => {
    const id = event.target.id;
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log("Value of the button: ", value)
    console.log("Id of the button: ", id)}
```